# Not collectively exhaustive events, but complement of the events is empty set

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I'm confused about one of my problems.

Consider events A,B,C, with probabilities P(A)=$2/10$, P(B)=$3/10$, P(C)=$4/10$

$A^c\cap B^c \cap C^c = \emptyset $

Is this possible to have the statement above correct, where the intersection of each event's complement is equal to the empty set?

Comment: Consider what happens if $A \subset B \subset C$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If $\ A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c=\emptyset\ $, then $\ P\big(A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c\big)=0\ $, so
$$
1=P\big(\big(A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c\big)^c\big)=
P(A\cup B\cup C)\ .
$$
Given the values of $\ P(A)\ $, $\ P(B)\ $ and $\ P(C)\ $, is it possible for this equation to hold?

Comment: Thanks for help!